# Use Phonegap without Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm quite new to Phonegap and would like to do it without Eclipse.
I've created several times a project this week but then suddenly Eclipse always freezes. Can't explain it.

So now I thought maybe I don't need Eclipse as IDE. So I tried it with Sublime Text.
With the CLI Phonegap 3.5 I created my project and tested it with

```
phonegap install android
```

So far no problem here.
But now I guess the cordova/phonegap.js won't really work.
In Phonegap 3.5 there is "www" as symlink in the root folder. This folder should point to "platforms/android/assets/www". Because there is the cordova.js and phonegap.js.

So when I installing the app on the emulator I can always see "connection to device" and "device is ready". I'm not sure but normally it should display only one status.

Is this a problem with the new version 3.5?
In Eclipse I had to remove the symlink to the "www"-folder to work in the android folder.
If I do this everything is fine. But without Eclipse and removing the www folder I stuck here.

Comment: **device is ready** status means cordova is working perfectly.

Comment: Yes I know, but I can also read the status "connecting to device". So both status can't be correct.

Comment: What is your actual problem?? If device ready is fired, that means everything is ok. Start coding. If that isn't fired, then something is wrong.